# Unable to generate an error in a case of swap with help of pointers

Tags: c++

I was trying to generate an error in swap code in C++. Interestingly, instead of an error, it successfully shows the opposite. My code look like this:

```
#include<iostream>  
using namespace std; 

void swap(int *x, int *y)                                                        
{                                                                                
    int *tmp = x;                                                                
    x = y;                                                                       
    y = tmp;                                                                     
}

int main()                                                                       
{                                                                                
    int u = 10;                                                                  
    int v = 20;                                                                  
    int * p = &u;                                                                
    int * q = &v;                                                  
    swap(*p, *q);                                                                
    std::cout<<"u :-"<<u<<" v  :-"<<v<<endl;                                     
    return 0;                                                                    
}
```

The value of `u` and `v` got swapped. In this, I am passing pointer value instead of reference but the value gets swapped, How?

Exact code can be found at:
https://ideone.com/kMJHL6

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
swap(*p, *q);
```

Since the type of `*p` and `*q` are **not** `int *`, (it's just `int`) this code *doesn't* call your `swap` function. Instead, it calls the function `std::swap`, which is in standard C++ library, by function overloading resolving.

Your code has `using namespace std;` - your case is one of examples that show why you shouldn`t use it.

Answer (score 6):

I think that you're calling the swap function of algorithm library, and not your function

Comment: Yes u re correct, but how does it do this.There is nothing called automatically calling the library. It must be doing some way.

Comment: I'm not sure, but probably he is using std namespace and this call swap function of algorithm library. But is my supposition, I'm not sure about this

Comment: @nebi: _"There is nothing called automatically calling the library."_ There absolutely is. It's called `using namespace std` and you should stop!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Pls enlighten me, where I am going and what I had to stop? I just raised my question and ikh and Frank answered it correctly and i am thankful to them. Pls do not make this an issue out of nothing and yes some self claimed vigilante deleted my comment thanking to irk. Probably u should look into that.!!

Comment: @nebi: What? I'm just saying you shouldn't write `using namespace std`. You don't need to bite my head off over it.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Didn't intended to bite anyone's head.